# EC2 (t1.micro) Windows XAMPP Can't Connect via web

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, xampp

I have opened a micro instance on AWS with a Windows_Server-2008-R2_SP1-English-64Bit-Base-2013.11.13 (ami-1e53c82e) virtual machine.  RDS is open and I have connected with remote desktop connection.  Additionally, at initialization I set HTTP (port 80), and HTTPS (port 443) although I do not know how to verify that now. From within the VM I navigated to XAMPP and installed a default installation (minus MySQL).  I then navigated to XAMPP control panel V3.2.1 and started Apache.  I set a password on XAMPP directory.  I set a "Hello World" test txt file in htdoc and that loads in the VM browser. However, when I try to access the pubic IP, my local browser times out.

I think I covered the first three checks on 
"xampp configuration in windows server 2008 r2 ec2 instance" post

but not sure how to change the elastic or private IP response if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VPC, you have to allow both inbound/outbound in the network ACL and inbound for the security group. You probably also have to open the ports in the windows firewall.

Edit: You definitely don't want to disable the firewall altogether. Also, it doesn't matter whether you use public ips from within AWS. And public host names resolve locally anyway.

Comment: Sorry, all that was over my head.  So at this time I understand modifying the security group by selections while creating the instance.  I do not know how to modify them in this virtual environment.